# get indexes for split string

Tags: javascript, string

How can I use the [str.split()](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_split.asp) function to get an array of indexes of the matches instead of the actual matches?

e.g.:

```js
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog."
console.log(str.split(' '));
//["The", "quick", "brown", "fox", "jumps", "over", "the", "lazy", "dog."] 

//I want to get this output instead for the index positions of the matches
//[0, 4, 10, 16, 20, 26, ...] 

//01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 
//The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.
```

Even better yet, this 2D array output would be ideal:

```js
//[[0, "The"], [4, "quick"], [10, "brown"], [16, "fox"], [20, "jumps"], [26, "over"], ...]
```

Comment: you will have to use a loop with conjunction of indexOf()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this method:

```
function splitWithIndex(str, delim){
 var ret=[]
 var splits=str.split(delim)
 var index=0
 for(var i=0;i<splits.length;i++){
  ret.push([index,splits[i]])
  index+=splits[i].length+delim.length
 }
 return ret
}
```

Example:

```
alert(splitWithIndex(str,' '))
```

EDIT (Dec. 17, 2018):  Avoid adding methods to native String object.

Answer (score 3):

If all the words are unique, you could do this:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rWJ5x/

```
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";

var arr = str.split(' ');

for( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    arr[i] = str.indexOf( arr[i] );
}
```

If there are repeating words, this should do it:

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/rWJ5x/2/

```
var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy brown dog.";
var pos = 0;

var arr = str.split(' ');

for( var i = 0, len = arr.length; i < len; i++ ) {
    var idx = str.indexOf( arr[i] );
    arr[i] = pos = (pos + idx);
    str = str.slice( idx );
}
```

Comment: +1 Thanks I accepted another solution that yields the 2D array.

Comment: @fortuneRice: Yeah I figured you could handle that. Required changing one line to add a few extra characters. `arr[i] = [pos = (pos + idx), arr[i]];`

Answer (score 3):

```
function wordIndexes(s){
    var A= [], rx=  /([a-zA-Z']+)/g, M;
    while((M= rx.exec(s))!= null){
        A.push([M.index, M[1]]);
    }
    return A;
}


var string= 'The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.';
wordIndexes(string).join('\n');
// returned value:
0, The
4, quick
10, brown
16, fox
20, jumps
26, over
31, the
35, lazy
40, dog
```

Answer (score 1):

The following method is a simple linear sweep over the string. It is faster than the combination of split() and indexOf(). In addition it yields the complete "2D" result (BTW the numbering in the question is not correct).

```
function wordIndexes(str) {
    var result = [];
    var len = str.length;
    var i = 0, j, word;
    while (i < len) {
        if (str[i] === ' ') {
            ++i;
        }
        else {
            word = "";
            for (j = i; j < len && str[j] !== ' '; ++j) {
                word += str[j];
            }
            result.push([i, word]);
            i = j;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

var str = "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.";
//         01234567890123456789012345678901234567890123456789 
var result = wordIndexes(str);
// => result = [[0, "The"], [4, "quick"], [10, "brown"], [16, "fox"], ...]
```

Comment: +1 Thanks this linear sweep might be faster but I decided to go with one that combines split and indexOf for easier code reading.

Comment: Thanks for looking at my suggestion (and for +1 :).